# How do you bold only one part of a sentence using google apps scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am using google apps scripts and I am trying to have a button that pastes "**Motion**—_____ moved and _____ seconded that _____." in a google doc. To only highlight the first six letters I have used the below code but I keep getting this error message:

> Exception: The parameters (number,number,(class)) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.Paragraph.setBold.

Instead of `(1, 6, true)` I've also tried `(parseInt('1'),parseInt('6'),true)`, and `(one, six, true)`, `('one', 'six', true)`. What does it want from me?

````
function motion() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var par1m = body.appendParagraph('Motion—_____ moved and _____ seconded that _____.');
    par1m.setBold(1, 6, true);
    par1m.setItalic(false);
    par1m.setUnderline(false);
    par1m.setStrikethrough(false);
    par1m.setFontFamily("Times New Roman");
    par1m.setFontSize(12);
    par1m.setForegroundColor('#000000');
    par1m.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);```
````

Comment: Have you tried `.setBold(true)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Paragraph` doesn't  have a *documented* `setBold()` attribute. `Text` does. Use [`editAsText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph?hl=en#editastext) to get a `Text` version:

```
var par1m = body.appendParagraph('Motion—_____ moved and _____ seconded that _____.').editAsText();
```

Comment: That works, thank you!